# How to movable notes on android home screen using widgets

Tags: android

I have work on sticky note app. How I can show sticky note on android home screen so that user get view easily. I am already use widgets but what I want is is it possible to move widgets on home screen by end user. Is it possible?

Thanks for the help.

I know widgets but will widget support runtime size change? Can user minimize size of widget at runtime like windows OS todo list

I know widgets but can resizing of screens is possible or I need to use some gaming framework like coco2d or libgdx

Comment: @Waza_Be, Simon, Pratik, sschaef, Sudarshan Can you reopen question? Please read it. I have edit it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. That's called a widget.

All documentation is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Do you have something specific to ask? I don't understand your question....

Comment: I am new to android programming.I need to show sticky notes on homescreen so can I interact with those notes means move on screen?